# Insert text to file starting with X column

Tags: linux, sed

Expected behaviour (empty columns at the beggining):

```
  "PostgreSQL" : {
    "Host" : "localhost",
    "Port" : 5432,
    "Database" : "dbname",
    "Username" : "dbuser",
    "Password" : "dbpass",
  },
```

My current command when I want to insert this on 46th line of json file:

```
sed -i '46i    "PostgreSQL" : {\n    "Host" : "localhost",\n    "Port" : 5432,\n    "Database" : "dbname",\n    "Username" : "dbuser",\n    "Password" :"dbpass",\n  },' file.json
```

Buth these whitespaces between 46i and "PostgreSQL" don't affect on text and starts from first column. How can I fix this? Or maybe there is more elegant way to reach the goal? I think about printf or echo, but I have to insert this text on specific line.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way, in my experience, is to save the text you want to insert as a file with the correct whitespace/formatting, then use sed to insert the `text_to_be_inserted.txt` into the file, e.g.

```
cat text_to_be_inserted.txt
  "PostgreSQL" : {
    "Host" : "localhost",
    "Port" : 5432,
    "Database" : "dbname",
    "Username" : "dbuser",
    "Password" : "dbpass",
  },

# Insert text from `text_to_be_inserted.txt` into 'file.txt' at line 46 with
sed '46 r text_to_be_inserted.txt' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash):

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '46{h;s/\S.*//;s/.*/cat -|sed "s#^#&  #"/ep;x}' file
"PostgreSQL" : {
  "Host" : "localhost",
  "Port" : 5432,
  "Database" : "dbname",
  "Username" : "dbuser",
  "Password" : "dbpass",
},
!
```

This inserts the here-document before line 46 of the input file retaining the indentation at line 46 and incrementing it by a further 2 spaces.

To append after line 46 retaining the same indentation, use:

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '46{p;s/\S.*//;s/.*/cat -|sed "s#^#&#"/ep;d}' file
"PostgreSQL" : {
  "Host" : "localhost",
  "Port" : 5432,
  "Database" : "dbname",
  "Username" : "dbuser",
  "Password" : "dbpass",
},
!
```